# .htaccess 301 redirect from main domain to subdomain

Tags: .htaccess

What should I put in .htaccess to redirect all links from main domain to subdomain? I have it like that but it doesnt wok:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://example.com/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subdomain.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried without the `http://` and the `/` at the end in the first line ?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$  [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subdomain.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Tried now and nothing happens. Could it be hosting issue?

Comment: I don't think so. When you go to your site, the url doesn't have the www at the beginning right ? Because the code above catch **example.com** not **www.example.com**

Comment: I have it set up like that:
/www/ <- in this folder I have your .htaccess file and my main domain files.
/www/mySubDomain <- in this folder I have my subdomain files.

When I type into browser:
mydomain.com <- adress will stay without www

but when I type:
www.mydomain.com <- adress will stay with www

Comment: On the other hand when I type www.mysubdomain.com it always transforms into mysubdomain.com. Tried your suggestion with www, didn't work.

Comment: And you want both URLs : www and non-www to redirect to subdomain.domain.com , right ?

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I want. Now nothing happens regarding both of adresses.

Comment: Have you `RewriteEngine On` on top of your htaccess file ? And mod_rewrite enable on your Apache server ?

Comment: ok works - had no rewrite engine, first time doing this:) thanks!

Comment: Cool ! I have edit my answer to fit your need for your two kinds of URLs (www and non-www). Also, don't forget to mark your question as solved ;-)